# Rewrite simple script from MySQL to SQlite3

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have few lines of script wrote in MySQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log ON STORMTROOPER
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE
  select 'updated stormstrooper ' + cast(d.id as nvarchar) + ' in ' + SQUAD.[name] + ' of ' + PLATOON.[name] + ' from rank ' + d.[rank] + ' to ' + i.[rank]
  from deleted d
  inner join inserted i on (i.ID = d.ID)
  inner join SQUAD on SQUAD.[id] = i.[squadId]
  inner join PLATOON on PLATOON.[id] = SQUAD.[platoonId]
END
```

but my interpretation in SQlite3 gives me an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER UPDATE ON STORMTROOPER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT 'Updated stormtrooper ' + CAST(d.id AS varchar2) + ' in ' + SQUAD.id + ' squad of ' + PLATOON.id + ' platoon, ' + COMPANY.id + ' company, ' + BATTALION.id + ' battalion from rank ' + d.rank + ' to ' + i.rank
FROM deleted d
INNER JOIN inserted i ON (i.id = d.id)
INNER JOIN SQUAD ON SQUAD.id = i.squad
INNER JOIN PLATOON ON PLATOON.id = SQUAD.platoon
INNER JOIN COMPANY ON COMPANY.id = PLATOON.company
INNER JOIN BATTALION ON BATTALION.id = COMPANY.battalion
GROUP BY d.id;
END;
```

How should it looks like in SQlite3?

Comment: When I'm using sqlfiddle.com the error is - "could not prepare statement (1 near "id": syntax error); When I'm writing this in terminal in my database there is no error, but doesn't work either.

Comment: You're not doing anything visible in the trigger; your select results will be discarded. Also `||` is the concat operator in SQL, not `+`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Could you write this for me?